# Sparkling water: Can't make use of the support of spark ml pipelines

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib, h2o, sparkling-water

According to [this](http://blog.h2o.ai/2016/06/spam-detection-with-sparkling-water-and-spark-machine-learning-pipelines/) blog by the Sparkling water guys, you are now able to use the Spark ML pipelines components to build a DL model in the latest versions. I tried adding the latest versions in my `build.sbt`

```
"org.apache.spark" % "spark-mllib_2.10" % "2.0.0" % "provided",
"ai.h2o" % "sparkling-water-core_2.10" % "1.6.5" % "provided"
```

but no luck, trying to import `org.apache.spark.ml.h2o.H2OPipeline` doesn't work. The `h2o` package inside `spark.ml` doesn't seem to exist in the spark jars. Even though it seems to work in the above link as well as [here](https://github.com/h2oai/sparkling-water/blob/master/examples/pipelines/hamOrSpam.script.scala).I really want to reuse my spark-mllib feature transformers to create a DL model using h2o, as shown in the blog.

Any help appreciated!

Thanks.

Comment: not sure if that's the problem but you're using Spark 2.0 with Sparkling Water 1.6.5, you should use Sparkling Water 2.0 which was released recently.

Comment: I doubt that's the case. https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/ai.h2o/sparkling-water-core_2.10 has only until `1.6.8` released.

Comment: Besides we are talking about the missing package from `org.apache.spark.ml` right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) please dont use spark 2 with sw 1.6.5 - it won't work. We released sw2.0 for scala 2.11 https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/ai.h2o/sparkling-water-core_2.11

2) you're only adding SW core in your build, the classes you are looking for are in sparkling-water-ml https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/ai.h2o/sparkling-water-ml_2.11

Comment: Thanks! It would be great if you could also point me to some documentation related to the ml pipelines support for sparkling water.

Comment: @void unfortunately we don't have much in terms of documentation as we're still implementing this and consider it an experimental feature. For now we only support H2O's GBM and DeepLearning as part of the pipelines (here's some example code https://github.com/h2oai/sparkling-water/blob/master/examples/pipelines/hamOrSpam.script.scala). We are very open to contributions :-)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply! Please point me to any issues (jira) related to adding more algorithm support to pipelines? I would like to keep track.

Answer (score 0):

I have used below versions for running H2O example with Maven pom.xml and it is working

- **Spark - 1.6**
- **Sparkling water - 1.6.8**
- **ai h2o - 3.10.0.8**

Here is maven pom.xml (please refer to GIT repo - https://github.com/seerampavan/H2oTesting/blob/master/pom.xml)

```
<properties>
    <spark.version>1.6.0-cdh5.7.1</spark.version>
    <scala.version>2.10.4</scala.version>
    <scala.binary.version>2.10</scala.binary.version>
    <top.dir>${project.basedir}/..</top.dir>
    <hadoop.version>2.6.0-cdh5.7.1</hadoop.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <!-- Force import of Spark's servlet API for unit tests -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
        <artifactId>scala-library</artifactId>
        <version>${scala.version}</version>
        <!--<scope>provided</scope>-->
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-core_${scala.binary.version}</artifactId>
        <version>${spark.version}</version>

        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <!-- make sure wrong scala version is not pulled in -->
                <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
                <artifactId>scala-library</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <!-- make sure wrong scala version is not pulled in -->
                <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
                <artifactId>scalap</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-sql_${scala.binary.version}</artifactId>
        <version>${spark.version}</version>

    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-hive_${scala.binary.version}</artifactId>
        <version>${spark.version}</version>

    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-mllib_${scala.binary.version}</artifactId>
        <version>${spark.version}</version>

        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.jpmml</groupId>
                <artifactId>pmml-model</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>

    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-streaming_${scala.binary.version}</artifactId>
        <version>${spark.version}</version>

    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-streaming-kafka_${scala.binary.version}</artifactId>
        <version>${spark.version}</version>

    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-streaming_${scala.binary.version}</artifactId>
        <version>${spark.version}</version>
        <type>test-jar</type>
        <classifier>tests</classifier>

    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.scalatest</groupId>
        <artifactId>scalatest_${scala.binary.version}</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.1</version>

    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.12</version>

    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
        <artifactId>hadoop-client</artifactId>
        <version>${hadoop.version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>log4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
                <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
                <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.jruby</groupId>
                <artifactId>jruby-complete</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.jboss.netty</groupId>
                <artifactId>netty</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>io.netty</groupId>
                <artifactId>netty</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
        <artifactId>scala-reflect</artifactId>
        <version>2.10.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ai.h2o</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2o-web</artifactId>
        <version>3.10.0.8</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ai.h2o</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2o-scala_2.10</artifactId>
        <version>3.10.0.8</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ai.h2o</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2o-persist-s3</artifactId>
        <version>3.10.0.8</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ai.h2o</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2o-persist-hdfs</artifactId>
        <version>3.10.0.8</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ai.h2o</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2o-parquet-parser</artifactId>
        <version>3.10.0.8</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ai.h2o</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2o-genmodel</artifactId>
        <version>3.10.0.8</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ai.h2o</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2o-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.10.0.8</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ai.h2o</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2o-bindings</artifactId>
        <version>3.10.0.8</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ai.h2o</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2o-avro-parser</artifactId>
        <version>3.10.0.8</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ai.h2o</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2o-app</artifactId>
        <version>3.10.0.8</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ai.h2o</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2o-algos</artifactId>
        <version>3.10.0.8</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ai.h2o</groupId>
        <artifactId>sparkling-water-repl_2.10</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.8</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ai.h2o</groupId>
        <artifactId>sparkling-water-ml_2.10</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.8</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ai.h2o</groupId>
        <artifactId>sparkling-water-examples_2.10</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.8</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ai.h2o</groupId>
        <artifactId>sparkling-water-core_2.10</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.8</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ai.h2o</groupId>
        <artifactId>deepwater-backend-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
        <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
        <version>2.9.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.joda</groupId>
        <artifactId>joda-convert</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.javassist</groupId>
        <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
        <version>3.22.0-CR1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>gov.nist.math</groupId>
        <artifactId>jama</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
        <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        <version>2.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ai.h2o</groupId>
        <artifactId>reflections</artifactId>
        <version>0.9.11-h2o-custom</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ai.h2o</groupId>
        <artifactId>google-analytics-java</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.2-H2O-CUSTOM</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.tony19</groupId>
        <artifactId>named-regexp</artifactId>
        <version>0.2.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
        <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-s3</artifactId>
        <version>1.11.45</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
        <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-kms</artifactId>
        <version>1.11.45</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
        <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.11.45</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty.aggregate</groupId>
        <artifactId>jetty-servlet</artifactId>
        <version>8.2.0.v20160908</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty.aggregate</groupId>
        <artifactId>jetty-server</artifactId>
        <version>8.2.0.v20160908</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty.aggregate</groupId>
        <artifactId>jetty-plus</artifactId>
        <version>8.1.17.v20150415</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```